# How is serial voting spread over a long period of time addressed?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

I could be wrong but I suspect that somebody whose serial down-votes of a couple of my posts has now down-voted just one.  Referencing the screenshot below you can see that just in the last couple of days, a couple of down-votes against questions of mine were reversed, but also one of the very same questions has since been individually down-voted.  Also you can see I don't get very many questions down-voted -- in fact there are no others on the rest of the first page (besides the one indicated near the very bottom of the screenshot), one on the second page, and none on the third page, going back a year.

It could of course just be a coincidence that this latest down-vote came so soon after one on an identical question that got reversed.  Still though, I'm interested in how such a scenario is addressed, if in fact the same user has come back to the same question to down-vote it, and perhaps intends on coming back maybe every day or every other day and possibly down-vote a dozen or more of my questions (or the questions of anybody else who might find themselves in such a scenario) in a month.

Is this recognizable as serial down-voting especially if by the same user whose down-votes were initially reversed, or possibly by a consistent IP address and therefore perhaps by a sock-puppet?  Or even if not from the same-user/same-IP just a lot more down-votes against a user's questions than usual over a relatively short period of time, when a user's questions haven't even been down-voted a half-dozen times in a year for instance: is this recognized as serial down-voting?  [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/141452) does not appear to answer my questions in the affirmative (in fact now upon closer reading of the answer it says such votes *can* be re-cast), and if not, are there or should there by any plans to address at least some of the scenarios I've described?
[image: Possible down-vote by previous serial down-voter]

Comment: @SagarV Not really a duplicate of that question at all, that question asks about flagging questions, my question asks about whether the system recognizes a particular scenario and/or if there is a mechanism or should be one to deal with such a scenario

Comment: the system won't recognise this and you have to flag it. but the chances are very low because you can't say for sure that both are same person.

Comment: A single vote is *very hard to prove intent for*. We can't possibly know if that was a revenge vote or a genuine vote on the content.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If someone that has previously serially downvoted a specific user, then downvotes a user once if he sees the votes are reversed, that's intent to me. And if it indeed was the same user, he will have noticed that the votes got reversed as it also is the same question.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: moderators can't see if it was the same user. We can only see patterns, and 1 vote is not a pattern. Now, if the *other* posts that were part of the first series now start receiving votes too, but further apart, there might be a case. But even if we could see this was the same user, I'd still decline to revert here.

Comment: Imagine how little must be going on in the life of someone who has the time and energy to dedicate themselves to downvoting others this way over a prolonged period of time. Imagining it helps ignoring the matter, which is the best course of action.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "But even if we could see this was the same user, I'd still decline to revert here."  What's your rationale?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: because a single vote two days later is still not a clear intent, in the wider context that I can see as a moderator.

Comment: There's ultimately no way of knowing the intent behind a vote, and it's possible to make serial voting look like legit voting if you distribute it across a long enough period of time. There's nothing a moderator can do about that. Sock puppets can be hard to catch. But as said, imagining the energy it takes for someone to do all this and laughing it off really is the recommendable thing to do :) This happens to most of us at some point or another. Eventually, those users just give up because it's so pointless.

Comment: Did you: leave any comments lately that could be interpreted as nonconstructive or rude? Down voted competing posts? Close voted anything? Edited/rolledback a post?  If any of these is yes or maybe, you have made new *friends*. This happens, sadly.

Comment: Ultimately I think going after this is kinda pointless. So someone had so little actually productive stuff to do and was so petty to do this to you. The best you can do to invalidate their efforts is to not care.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no system level mechanism for automatically dealing with this.

You can however raise a moderator flag on one of your posts or write to the team at the "contact us" link at the foot of every page. Moderators can't see who voted for whom, so if anyone will be able to fix this, it'll be the staff.

On the flipside, you have to ask yourself if you care enough to pursue this getting fixed at all. That's a call you have to make.